# What is the meaning of this error message: lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/nes/.gvfs

Tags: gvfs, lsof

When I use `lsof` with `sudo` like this

```
sudo lsof ~


lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/nes/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

However, when I use it without `sudo`, I don't get this error.

What does this message mean?

Comment: What @jmtd said is correct. Give [How to get sudo access to shares mounted by Gigolo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401454/how-to-get-sudo-access-to-shares-mounted-by-gigolo/401509) a shot; it may help you get around it.

Comment: To whom it may concern, I get the same warning with and without `sudo` ( I am operating from tty1, but this shouldn't matter I presume)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a FUSE virtual filesystem mounted at `~/.gvfs`.

For the majority of filesystem accesses, permissions are ignored for the root user.  However, FUSE virtual filesystem mounts are one of the rare exceptions.  FUSE virtual filesystems are normally restricted to the user who mounted them.

In this case, the `gvfs-fuse-daemon` command (run as part of your desktop session) created this mount, belonging to you, and no-one else can access it, including root.

Comment: Then how to address it? In case I want to "sudo lso | grep ...".

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question in [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/): [lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171519/lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfsd-fuse-file-system) It has two interesting answers, which I'm quoting below.

##### [pabouk - Ukraine stay strong's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171525/322816):

> ### FUSE and its access rights
>
> `lsof` by default checks all mounted file systems including [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) - file systems implemented in user space which have special access rights in Linux.
>
> As you can see in this [answer on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/23199/67132) a mounted [GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) file system (special case of FUSE) is normally accessible only to the user which mounted it (the owner of `gvfsd-fuse`). Even `root` cannot access it. To override this restriction it is possible to use mount options `allow_root` and `allow_other`. The option must be also enabled in the FUSE daemon which is described for example in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/401509/67132) ...but in your case you do not need to (and should not) change the access rights.
>
> ### Excluding file systems from lsof
>
> In your case `lsof` does not need to check the GVFS file systems so you can exclude the `stat()` calls on them using the `-e` option (or you can just ignore the waring):
>
> ```
> lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs
> ```
>
> ### Checking certain files by lsof
>
> You are using `lsof` to get information about all processes running on your system and only then you filter the complete output using `grep`. If you want to check just certain files and the related processes use the `-f` option without a value directly following it then specify a list of files after the "end of options" separator `--`. This will be considerably faster.
>
> ```
> lsof -e /run/user/1000/gvfs -f -- /tmp/report.csv
> ```
>
> ### General solution
>
> To exclude all mounted file systems on which `stat()` fails you can run something like this (in `bash`):
>
> ```
> x=(); for a in $(mount | cut -d' ' -f3); do test -e "$a" || x+=("-e$a"); done
> lsof "${x[@]}" -f -- /tmp/report.csv
> ```
>
> Or to be sure to use `stat()` (`test -e` could be implemented a different way):
>
> ```
> x=(); for a in $(mount | cut -d' ' -f3); do stat --printf= "$a" 2>/dev/null || x+=("-e$a"); done
> ```

---

##### [Gilles 'SO- stop being evil''s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171580/322816):

> `lsof` always tries to obtain some basic information about all filesystems, even if the arguments happen to imply that no result will come from a particular filesystem. If it's unable to access a filesystem (specifically, to call `stat` at its mount point, as the message says), it complains.
>
> As root, you would normally have permission to access filesystems. However, due to the inner workings of [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace), root does not automatically have all powers on a FUSE filesystem. This isn't a security feature (root can become the user who owns the filesystem and get access that way), it's a technical limitation.
>
> GVFS-FUSE is a FUSE interface to [GVFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS), which is a mechanism that allows Gnome applications to access virtual filesystems implemented by Gnome plugins: GVFS grants non-Gnome applications access to these virtual filesystems via the regular filesystem interface.