# lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs Output information may be incomplete

Tags: grep, mongodb, fuse

I am using this command

```
sudo lsof | grep mongod | grep TCP
```

it shows record but first it shows below warning i am guesing its not showing me the whole list of open connection

```
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
```

please help

Comment: try the solutions at [lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171519/lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfsd-fuse-file-system) or [How to get sudo access to shares mounted by Gigolo](http://askubuntu.com/questions/401454/how-to-get-sudo-access-to-shares-mounted-by-gigolo/401509).

Comment: Try running: `sudo umount /run/user/1000/gvfs`

Comment: see the proper answer on this page https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171519/lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfsd-fuse-file-system

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What means this error message: lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/nes/.gvfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23074/what-means-this-error-message-lsof-warning-cant-stat-fuse-gvfs-fuse-daemon)